Объединить два датафрейма Pandas по ключу с помощью merge
При объединении двух датафреймов появляются лишние строки. Объясню на примере:
датафрейм1(50 строк), к нему присоединяю столбцы датафрейма2 (16 млн строк) по 4м ключам, получается итоговый датафрейм 51 строка. Причём это одна лишняя строка - дублирует одну из строк, т. е. по сути количество строк увеличивается за счет строк - дублеров. В чем может быть причина? Конечно можно удалить дублёры после, но хотелось бы чтобы они не образовывались изначально.
(По типам данных - всё нормально, проверяла)
Вот примеры кода (2 варианта):

df_merged1 = pd.merge(
    res_test1, df3_,
    left_on=['uuid',  'id_route', 'vehicle_type', 'time' ],
    right_on=['uuid',  'id_route', 'vehicle_type', 'time' ]
)

df_merged2 = res_test1.merge(df3_, on=['uuid',  'id_route', 'vehicle_type', 'time' ])


Объясню на примере: датафрейм1(50 строк), к нему присоединяю столбцы датафрейма2 (16 млн строк) по 4м ключам, получается итоговый датафрейм 51 строка. Например, какой-то записи фрейма 1 соответствуют две разные записи во фрейме 2.

Ну да, я бы сразу посмотрел, что это за дубль на выходе и попробовал по значениям его ключевых полей отобрать записи во втором датафрейме. Сразу всё понятно должно стать.

Спасибо, всем, кто откликнулся. Действительно датафрейм 2 содержал 2 записи к одной записи из датафрейма 1. Вы лучшие)))

Такое может происходить, если одному набору ключей в левой таблице соответствует несколько строк с таким же набором ключей в правой таблице.
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'1': [1, 2],
                              '2': ['a', 'b']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'1': [1, 2, 2, 3],
                              '3': ['a', 'd', 'd', 'c']})
result1 = pd.merge(df1, df2)
display(result1)

Получим:



1
2
3




1
a
a


2
b
d


2
b
d



Тогда нужно оставить лишь одну строку с уникальным набором ключей, используя drop_duplicates на правом наборе данных до слияния.
df_merged2 = res_test1.merge(df3_.drop_duplicates(['uuid',  'id_route', 'vehicle_type', 'time']), on=['uuid',  'id_route', 'vehicle_type', 'time' ])


Дефолтное значение у how там inner, а оно ещё строже. Ослабление условия тут не поможет. Нужно копать именно в сторону дублирующихся значений сочетания ключей.

Да, проверил на тестовых датафреймах. Тогда очевидно, что одному и тому же набору ключей из левой таблицы соответсвует две строки с таким же набором ключей в правой.
